# Create a PDF document after click a button in React

Tags: reactjs, pdf-generation

I want to generate a PDF document that is generated after user click "Create PDF document" for my current React page.  The document I want to generate will have the following:

1. Some, but not all component in the current page
2. Selectable
3. Only download the document when clicking and nowhere else

I have spent 3 hours researching on this trivial task, but somehow all library I have looking up for only allow their pre-defined component, or not selectable, or both. I know that this task is very trivial, but how exactly I could do that?

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is, having a separate component that only contains what data need to be downloaded. And you can pass all necessary data using props.

I recommend using this library [React-PDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-pdf/renderer).

**App.js**

```
import { PDFDownloadLink } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import Document from './Document.js'

export default function App() {

  const data = {/* Pass your data here  */}
  return (
    <div className="App">
            <PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDocument data={data}/>} fileName="somename.pdf">
                {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
                    loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!'
                }
            </PDFDownloadLink>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Document.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Document, Page, Text, View, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4'
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

// Create Document Component
const MyDocument = ({ data }) => ( // 
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>{data.something}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>{data.something}</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);
```

In the main component, you will have a **Download now!** button. Your PDF will only contain data that you pass through props